# Open the same Form again after Closing

Tags: powershell, user-interface, progress-bar

Either I'm too stupid to google it properly or the problem is too obvious to solve.

I'm using a second small form to display a progressbar when running a function (Loading some information takes some time and this adds some nice responsiveness)

After the function finished and data is retreived, the progressbar-form is Closed with `$formbar.Close()`

If I call the function in the same instance again the progressbar wont show again because it was already disposed. How do I change that? I'd prefer not to "hide" the progressbar.

```
$formbar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$progressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar

$formbar.ControlBox = $false
$formbar.Size = '265,45'
$formbar.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$progressBar1.Style = "Continuous"
$progressBar1.ForeColor = "#009374"
$ProgressRange = 1..100
$ProgressMinMax = $ProgressRange | Measure -Minimum -Maximum

$progressBar1.Location = '0,0'
$progressBar1.Size = '250,30'
$progressBar1.Visible = $True
$progressBar1.Minimum = $ProgressMinMax.Minimum
$progressBar1.Maximum = $ProgressMinMax.Maximum
$progressBar1.Step = 10
$formbar.Controls.Add($progressBar1)
$formbar.Show()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Recreate it from scratch every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-create the whole form every time:

```
function New-ProgressBarForm {
  $null = . {
    $formbar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $progressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar

    $formbar.ControlBox = $false
    $formbar.Size = '265,45'
    $formbar.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $progressBar1.Style = "Continuous"
    $progressBar1.ForeColor = "#009374"
    $ProgressRange = 1..100
    $ProgressMinMax = $ProgressRange | Measure -Minimum -Maximum

    $progressBar1.Location = '0,0'
    $progressBar1.Size = '250,30'
    $progressBar1.Visible = $True
    $progressBar1.Minimum = $ProgressMinMax.Minimum
    $progressBar1.Maximum = $ProgressMinMax.Maximum
    $progressBar1.Step = 10
    $formbar.Controls.Add($progressBar1)
  }

  return [pscustomobject]@{
    Form = $formbar
    ProgressBar = $progressBar1
  }
}
```

Then call:

```
$progress = New-ProgressBarForm
$progress.Form.Show()
```

When you want to display it

Answer (score 2):

Mathias answered the question, but you also asked why, so here's why.

When the user closes your form, either by the form being dismissed using the `X` or Close button, or when the `Form.Close()` method is closed, [the following takes place:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=net-5.0)

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your application, your application ends.

We can tell if its handles are still available by looking at the object's `IsDisposed` property.

```
#before showing
PS> $formBar.IsDisposed
False

PS> $formBar.Show()

PS> $formBar.IsDisposed
True
```

**TLDR**: it has to do with memory management.  Once a form is shown and then closed, its gone from memory, but the variables it touched will forever remain in our hearts.